# Automated paste one word at a time?

Tags: display, recording, copy-paste, video-editing

Has anyone seen some copy/paste software with the feature to paste one word at a time?

I am filming a demonstrative video and want it to appear I am typing a long-winded canned product description.

I'm using Camtasia recording studio on Windows XP to record data input in a website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[KeyText](http://www.keytext.com/) is "a useful keyboard macro and Windows automation program" . It has a "macro" mode that might do what you want:

> You can use its multiple clipboard
> capabilities to make the gathering and
> re-use of texts straightforward. And
> online chat users will love the
> "simulate manual typing" mode!

The [manual](http://www.keytext.com/ktextman.pdf) gives a bit more details:

> Macro simulates typing, at the speed
> set in the Settings dialog. It is
> slower than pasting, but has other
> advantages. The clipboard is not used,
> thus preserving its contents; and if
> your word-processor has auto- correct
> or auto-format capabilities, these
> will be available. For example, if
> your word-processor automatically
> superscripts ordinals such as st, nd,
> rd, th etc., this will only happen if
> the method chosen is Macro.
>
> Watching
> the text appear is also intriguing,
> while the KeyText icon gives a visual
> clue that typing is taking place. When
> KeyText is "typing" in your text, you
> can abort by pressing [Esc] or by
> left-clicking the KeyText icon.

It's not free unfortunately: its price is $29.95.

Comment: Comes with a free demo which lets me store 20 canned-responses, and easily paste them. Works perfectly for my job. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this would work but you could maybe create your document in advance then use a macro to copy it one character/word at time into a new document.

Answer (score 0):

Windows has a library specifically for this called "SendKeys". If you don't want to pay money and you have some tech savvy read [this post](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-1056137.html).

You can probably google sendkeys and find a program that somebody's written and use it. I am also assuming you're using Windows.

Answer (score 0):

It should be fairly easy to write a program that will parse your ready-made description and spit it out to the standard output one word, or even one character, at a time.

If you are not a programmer, I, or anyone on StackOverflow, can help you with that... should be 5 minutes work.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at **[Phrase Express](http://www.phraseexpress.com/)**, not particularly designed for what you have in mind, but it might be just what you're looking for. of course you can use 'single words' rather than 'complete phrases'.

Phrase Express is free for personal use. a portable version is also available.

Answer (score 0):

If the software you write in has a long undo history:

You could write everything then do `ctrl-delete` until all the text is gone. Then when you want to pretend you are typing just keep pressing `ctrl-z` :)